# Как обработать PL/SQL исключение, соответствующее коду ORA-02291?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Например, имеется ошибка:

> ORA-00001: дублированный ключ в индексе

К ней есть соответствующее исключение `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`.

Какое исключение соответствует ошибке с кодом `ORA-02291`?

> ORA-02291: нарушено ограничение целостности?

Или каким ещё образом можно обработать исключение с таким кодом?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/23239172

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите список [Predefined Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-8C327B4A-71FA-4CFB-8BC9-4550A23734D6).
Если там нет исключения с нужным кодом  (кода ошибки `-2291` там нет), то есть две возможности:

```
begin
    declare
        integrity_constraint_violated exception ;
        pragma exception_init (integrity_constraint_violated, -2291);
    begin
        raise integrity_constraint_violated;
    exception when integrity_constraint_violated then
        dbms_output.put_line ('exception integrity_constraint_violated catched');
        raise;
    end;    
exception when others then
    if sqlcode = -2291 then 
        dbms_output.put_line ('exception code -2291 catched');
    end if;
    raise;
end;
/
```

Результатом выполнения будет:

```
exception integrity_constraint_violated catched
exception code -2291 catched

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (.) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at line 15
```

---

Заметьте, что нельзя записать, в какой таблице и какой ключ нарушен, т.е. вот это `(.)`.
Это могут только внутренние функции БД, которые проверяют ограничение.